# Tests failing to run from VSTS : System.MissingMethodException: Method not found

Tags: .net, azure-devops, mstest

I am using NJsonSchema nuget library for schema validation in my MSTest tests. They run fine when I run them on my PC but fail when runs from VSTS with following error.

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1 NJsonSchema.JsonSchema4.Validate(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)'.

I have checked all the required dlls are there on default directory where tests are run from.

Could anyone please point to the right direction ?

VSTS log

Test method AIS.e2eIntegration.ClientTest.E2E_GetClient_Expand threw exception: 
2017-12-13T14:14:54.3074393Z System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1 NJsonSchema.JsonSchema4.Validate(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)'.
2017-12-13T14:14:54.3075218Z Stack Trace:
2017-12-13T14:14:54.3075875Z     at AIS.e2eIntegration.Utilities.ValidateSchema(IRestResponse response, JsonSchema4 schema)
2017-12-13T14:14:54.3076619Z    at AIS.e2eIntegration.ClientTest.d__11.MoveNext()
2017-12-13T14:14:54.3077317Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2017-12-13T14:14:54.3078414Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2017-12-13T14:14:54.3079336Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2017-12-13T14:14:54.3080532Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)
2017-12-13T14:14:54.3080994Z

Comment: What's the detail code? Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? Can you post the detail log here (set system.debug to true and queue build and post the log here)? Provide the detail steps to reproduce this issue. (I created a unit test project and install NJsonSchema package, validate schema in code by using JsonSchema4.Validate(JToken) method, it works fine during the test in VSTS)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I have updated the post logs.

Comment: Post the whole log here or share in OneDrive.

Comment: How did this issue end up? I have a similar one with System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: "Void NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings.set_SerializerSettings(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings)". But it seems to work on some other systems.

Comment: @skaddy : Its been a while since I posted the question. As far as I remember, it was case of missing library on the VSTS/Azure DevOps agent.